# Is it possible to make an optically functional camera lens in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am interested and intrigued at the idea of designing a camera lens (or camera lense**s**) in Blender, that would function optically like "normal" camera lenses and project an image on a plane.

By *"optically functional camera lens"*, I mean something like this, where the image of the scene comes into the lens and out the other end onto a plane (image courtesy of [this site](http://rags-int-inc.com)):

[image]

This is not a tutorial request, I am just asking before I get into this time-consuming project if someone knows whether or not this would technically work or if it wouldn't, because of [the current limitations of Blender's caustics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48223/creating-beautiful-caustics-in-cycles) simulator (and yes, I understand that the rendering could take a very long time...). I am not extremely knowledgeable about optics and cannot tell if the two are related.

Oddly (or maybe just because people aren't masochists), I can't find much on the subject, [besides from this old post with broken links](http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-68149.html).

Comment: Yes the two are related - caustics and the image of the tree on the film. They are the same. So because of this limitation Cycles can't do that

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9091/can-blender-be-used-for-simple-optical-modeling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already tried things like this, but on a much smaller scale. If you want to be sure that your project works, you should try [Luxrender](http://www.luxrender.net/en_GB/index) because it is based on a physical simulation.

Comment: Thanks! I'd love to see some of your tests to decide is it's worth it to get into this