# How to render realistic glass with refracted shadows in Cycles (as pictured)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, shadows, glass, photorealism

Is it possible to render in cycles refractive shadows through glass texture (as pictured)?

[image: Example of realistic glass shadows]

I have tried varying light bounces, specular lighting and increasing samples, perhaps my setup isn't powerful enough to try the very highest, although I am not sure that will enhance the refraction in the shadows - my current state of rendering (may download .blend file below):

[image]

Thank you in advance for your advice and help!

I have attached .blend file if this helps http://www.mediafire.com/file/wqycarzifbql3b6/Glasses.blend/file

Comment: Hello :). These are called *Caustics*, and unfortunately you can't really get a good result with Cycles. Related: [Creating beautiful caustics in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/48223/78972)

Comment: Try Lux Renderer It has pretty caustics.

Comment: Thank you both - rapid helpful advice! I will investigate LuxCore Render engine now.