# Make cracks in crystal

Tags: modeling, node-editor

I want to make the rainbow cracks that are in the crystal on the picture below.
The crystal is not hard to make. The cracks is harder. I tried with Cell Fracture and Cell Fracture Crack It but the cracks is too...controled and even or rather the blocks between the cracks are. Even if I use the random option.

And I do not know how to set the nodes and the light to get those pretty rainbows.

I apreciate any help I can get.

/wave
[image]

Comment: The "pretty rainbows" are caused by light spectrum dispersion which is not physically possible with Cycles renderer. It's fakeable, look into https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1602/light-spectrum-dispersion-effect-in-blender and https://cgcookie.com/lesson/dispersion and search by the keywords "blender cycles light spectrum dispersion"

Comment: A complicated node set up but might help, https://www.artstation.com/artwork/KdDxx