# Can I model a transparent prism in Blender

Tags: objects

Prisms can split while light into coloured components. As Blender is not really a full simulation system for light, I’m guessing that effects of light splitting by prisms or such like can only be faked. Has anyone tried?

Comment: maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1603/19287

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40226/how-to-construct-a-diamond-or-other-gemstone-material-in-cycles/40836#40836