# What is the most physically correct glass shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, light, glass

What node setup is the most physically correct? I mean, wich is the glass shader that looks the most like real life? The glass shader that makes the light rays act like real life.

Answer (score 3):

"Glass" is too vague; there are many kinds of glass with many different optical properties. See [refractiveindex.info](https://refractiveindex.info/?shelf=glass&book=BK7&page=SCHOTT) to get some idea of the number of parameters you can worry about.

As far as cycles is concerned, a plain glass shader is as close as you probably care to get before increasing render times too much. Though absorption may be applicable with colored glass.

While there [are ways to approximate other phenomena like dispersion in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1602/599), if you are serious about simulating those you are likely better off using a spectral renderer like [luxrender](https://luxcorerender.org/).