# How to make light ray with Luxcore

Tags: light, luxrender-render-engine

I'm trying to make a realistic prism with Luxcore since yesterday but it's not really working, there's no ray! But I know that the prisme is working because if I put a plane in front of the prism I can see the light on it [image]
How could I do that ?

Comment: something like this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1602/light-spectrum-dispersion-effect-in-blender?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *World* tab you can add a volume to the entire scene. This allows you to create fog which scatters light from your laser and thus makes it visible. You will likely need to adjust the *Scattering Scale* to the size of your scene, larger values result in stronger scattering.

[image: World volume]
[image: Denoised preview render]

[image]

Comment: Its working but the render is really noisy, I tried your .blend file but it was noisy too, I think I need to render with my GPU but I don't know how https://i.imgur.com/aV1n882.jpg